# Connecting a shunt capacitor with a small resistance in series

Tags: resistance, high-voltage, high-current, bypass-capacitor

Will this circuit draw too much current from my power supply? I have this schematic that I found from similar work to mine. However, they seem to have used a very small resistance before the large shunt capacitor. Since this will operate at very high voltage (200V), will this scheme draw too much current? My lab power supply is only rated for 500 mA.
Thanks!

[image: Input voltage is 200V and the load is to the right]

Comment: Details of your lab power supply are needed.

Comment: If your lab power supply has a CC limit, the 10 ohm isn’t needed at all.

Comment: I have a GPR-H series 1000V 500mA supply. With both CC and CV mode

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly.

At steady state, the total resistance is 4.71 kΩ, although I'm quite wrongly assuming an ideal capacitor, so it depends on how much leaks through your capacitor as to whether this is ok, but probably.

At power on however, when the ideal capacitor presents a short, the current could be as high as 200 V/10 Ω = 20 A. 
This size capacitor can present problems in these transient conditions. It depends on how your power supply handles an over current, and what behavior you need. 
 If the power supply "Hiccups" for example, a behaviour where an over current causes a temporary shut off, and after a short time the power comes back on, you could be left with a supply constantly hiccuping.